# How to add a filter to a page in serenity?

Tags: c#, typescript

I'm trying to make a filter for a page in serenity.

I have a page called Companies, and one button to open another page, CompanyUsers, users from this company.

[image]

It's already opening the new page, but it's giving me all the users, I want to filter by the row I have clicked.

I have tried changing the Controller of CompanyUsers adding a parameter, but after this I don't know how to set the filter in CompanyUsers.

My Onclick in CompaniesGrid.ts

```
protected onClick(e: JQueryEventObject, row: number, cell: number): void {
            super.onClick(e, row, cell);

            let item = this.itemAt(row);

            if ($(e.target).hasClass('usuario-row')) {
                window.location.href = '/Cadastros/EmpresasUsuarios?empresaId=' + item.EmpresaId;
            }
        }
```

How can I do that with serenity ?
Is there an easy way to do that ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found how to do that......

WIth QuickFilter on column and getQuickFilters on Grid.ts

```
protected getQuickFilters() {
        var flt = super.getQuickFilters();

        var q = Q.parseQueryString();

        if (q["jEmpresa"]) {
            var empresa = Q.tryFirst(flt, x => x.field == "EmpresaId");
            empresa.init = e => {
                e.element.getWidget(Serenity.LookupEditor).value = q["jEmpresa"];
            };
        }

        return flt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick filters 
100% Working Code; try This Code

var q = Q.parseQueryString();

```
if (q["jEmpresa"]) {
    var empresa = Q.tryFirst(flt, x => x.field == "EmpresaId");
    empresa.init = e => {
        e.element.getWidget(Serenity.LookupEditor).value = q["jEmpresa"];
    };
}

return flt;
```

}